# Observable nearly commuting with a "complete" set of commuting observables

Tags: linear-algebra, oa.operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

Consider the Hilbert space $H = E^{\otimes n}$ where $E=\mathbb{C}^2$.

On $E$ we have an observable $O$ (i.e. a Hermitian matrix) that is diagonalizable in the standard basis with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$. By tensoring $O$ with the identity on $E^{\otimes n-1}$, and doing so for each of the $n$ possible positions for the factor $E$, we get a set of commuting observables $O_i$, $i=1\dots n$. An observable that commutes with all these observables must belong to the algebra generated by the $O_i$'s.

Now if I have an observable $M$ on $H$ such that the operator norm of $[M,O_i]$ is at most $1$ for all $i$, how far can $M$ be from the algebra generated by the $O_i$'s, in the operator norm? What are explicit examples that are far from the algebra?

Any pointer or relevant remark for related questions welcome.

Comment: The $O_i$ are not a complete set of commuting observables --- there aren't enough. The dimension of $H$ is $2^n$ not $n$.

Comment: (Unless you mean something different than I do by a "complete" set.)

Comment: @NikWeaver that's correct sorry. I meant the ring they generate is a complete set of commuting observables

Comment: @NikWeaver: I think the question is basically how far away $M$ is from the space of polynomials in the $O_i$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam that's correct, sorry for the bad phrasing

Comment: @alesia: not your fault. Dirac is to blame.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have 
$$
[\frac{1}{idx},x]=1/i
$$
although $\frac{1}{idx}$ is far from the Identity.

Comment: Yes, are you suggesting that taking the analog of this commutation relation over the finite field F_2^n instead of the reals would give an interesting example?

Comment: What does your fraction mean?  Should it be $\frac1 i\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}$, or is there really some meaning to $\frac1{\mathrm dx}$?

Comment: I think the question is really finite dimensional in nature and this example does not help much.